# How to use pycharm key map in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

How can I use same shortcuts in VSCode as in Pycharm, eg I want to run a code same as in Pycharm using `ctrl+shift+f10`, and I dont want to add all keymaps one by one in VScode ?
I tried to use plugins but not working, I cannot also find keybindings.json for PyCharm that I will be able to use in VSCode.

Comment: @rioV8 I want to map as much as possible from pycharm to VScode, settings etc, because I dont know much VSCode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an extension provided by the marketplace:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=isudox.vscode-jetbrains-keybindings

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33509860)